# OneDrive filled up my server - how to stop syncing a particular folder on a particular machine?

Tags: sync, disk-space, onedrive

Recently I moved all my phone pictures off my phone to my laptop SkyDrive / OneDrive folder.

I have a GoDaddy server that I use for development work.  It had about 6 GB free, and that space disappeared.

I found that the pictures had all synced to the server.

I want to keep OneDrive on the computer because I use it as a document repository.  However, I do not want the Pictures folder to be copied (synced) to the computer.  Pictures are irrelevant for the purposes of the server.

The server OS is Windows 2008 R2.

How can I stop the pictures being copied to the server disk?

Comment: Simplest way would be to get a seperate Onedrive accounts for the photos.

Answer (score 0):

On your GoDaddy server:

1. Right-click on the OneDrive icon in the lower-right corner.
2. Select "Settings.
3. In the dialog box that opens, select the "Choose folders" tab.
4. Select only the folders you want to sync on that machine.  Uncheck the rest including, in your case, the pictures folder.

Now the pictures will not be synched on that server.